# photoswipe 1.0.11 - doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, photoswipe

I try to work with photoswipe (downloaded here: http://github.com/downloads/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/code-photoswipe.v1.0.11.zip) on my mobile site. My problem is, that appearently the photoswipe doesn't fire.

My header is the following:

```
<link media="all" href="fileadmin/css/mobile/photoswipe.css?1406785972" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
<script src="fileadmin/js/libaries/simple-inheritance.min.js">
<script src="fileadmin/js/libaries/code-photoswipe-1.0.11.min.js">
<script src="fileadmin/js/libaries/photoswipe.js">
```

When I click on a picture, photoswipe doesn't start. I think you can see that best on my site itself: http://m.andre-hohmann.net/bilder/urlaubsbilder/tunesien-2010/. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/), you need to attach the Photoswipe's library when `DOMContentLoaded` is, well, loaded, like this:

```
// Set up PhotoSwipe with all anchor tags in the Gallery container 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var myPhotoSwipe = Code.PhotoSwipe.attach( window.document.querySelectorAll('#Gallery a'), { enableMouseWheel: false , enableKeyboard: false } );
}, false);
```

Note the `window.document.querySelectorAll('#Gallery a')` because that means that there's a DOM element with ID `Gallery` that has one or more `a` elements inside. All those `a` elements has then the Photoswipe library attached.

Comment: Hallo Patrick, I want to use the "Default Distribution with jQuery-engine", not the "Default Distribution", because I use jquery anyway.

Comment: It doesn't matter what kind of version you want to use. Either way, you'll need a way to tell the Photoswipe library to be attached to something. Probably, the only thing that's going to change from the code above is how you call the dom elements and how you attach events.

Comment: In general you're right. But e.g. I use jquery mobile I can call photoswipe in another way than I can when I only use jquery. I think if I call with jquery, the version of jquery is important, too: you can see that at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2xYpW/42/ Try version 1.9.1 of jquery (which I use and which doesn't work) and version 1.8.3 (which works!). Now I decided to work with the default; with this method to call photoswipe it works for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: The code from your JSFiddle (lines 136-139) does exactly what the code on the response above does: attach Photoswipe to a certain element. The only difference between using pure Javascript solution rather than a jQuery one is, maybe, that the jQuery version of Photoswipe attach itself to jQuery, so you can chain it with jQuery selectors.

Finally, if the response above helped you, please accept it. :)

Comment: The original question admittedly isn't really answered at all (I still don't know why photoswipe appearently doesn't work with newer versions of jquery), but I think I can close my question even so. Thank you very much.